# Sort an array in descending order php

Tags: php, sorting, ksort

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0px 0px
    [1] => -101px 0px
    [2] => -205px -3px
    [3] => 0px -77px
    [4] => -100px -80px
    [5] => -202px -80px
)
```

I would like to sort it in order to have:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => -202px -80px
        [1] => -100px -80px
        [2] =>  0px -77px
        [3] => -205px -3px
        [4] => -101px 0px
        [5] => 0px 0px
    )
```

Based on my research, the ksort() is supposed to do the trick but Im having 1.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_reverse()`: http://php.net/array_reverse

It reverses the array order as the name suggests.

Comment: Oh okay. It worked. Thanks. Will validate as when I am allowed to.

Comment: @Lomse So it is not a *sort* that you want, simply reverse the array...?

Comment: @Lomse the "wished result" appears to be a sorted array (first on *y* then on *x*) which is, then, reversed. It was my understanding that the OP wants a single operation to sort an array *descending*... (maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: @ring0 he's also talking about ksort; an indication that he wants to sort by key (he'd need krsort; what's in this case the same as array_reverse)